# Why my ajax code not run with Python Flask?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm just doing some simple request from ajax to Flask, but it doesn't work.

Here is my basic.html vs js/basic.js code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.ajax(type: 'GET', url: '/home/check').done(function(data){
      $('#status_id').text("Submitted");
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block main %}
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/basic.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>
<h1 id="status_id"></h1>
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" id = "urlInput" aria-describedby="urlHelp" placeholder="">
    <small id="urlHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Enter URL or some message to generate your QR code.</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate</button>
</form>
<img src="/static/images/new.png" alt="There is no image!">
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my python code, I've already register a blueprint called bp_home:

```
bp_home = Blueprint('home', __name__, url_prefix='/home')
@bp_home.route('/check')
def check():
    return jsonify({"isValid": "True"})

@bp_home.route('/basic_generator')
def basic_generator():
    return render_template('home/basic.html')
```

The above code doesn't work and when i submit the form, it automaticly redirect to GET method like this:
http://127.0.0.1:5000/home/basic_generator?url=
any suggest ??

Comment: Does `basic_generator` appear elsewhere in your code? If so, show us that bit of code.

Comment: I've edited, but I don't think it influences what I'm getting

Comment: is it because the absolute path in my script?

Answer (score 2):

I think I've solved it. The problem was that I'm using jquery.slim.min cdn version copying from bootstrap docs, which miss a lot of functionalities for ajax. Change it into jquery.min version, everything would be OK.